# Select last 2 values in each row in R

Tags: r

I'd like to select the last 2 values in each row in R (ignore the NA) and place the last 2 values in a new data.frame

this is a reproducible example

```
       V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
1      116 174  NA  NA  NA  NA
2       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
5       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
6       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
7       NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
957594 115 116 120 613 127 127
957595  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
957596  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA

 tss2 <- structure(list(V10 = c(116L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 115L, NA,NA),
    V11 = c(174L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 116L, NA, NA),
    V12 = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 120L, NA, NA),
    V13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, 613L, NA, NA),
    V14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,127L, NA, NA),
    V15 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 127L,
    NA,NA)), .Names = c("V10", "V11", "V12", "V13",
    "V14", "V15"), class = "data.frame", row.names
    = c(1L,2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 957594L, 957595L, 957596L))
```

the expected result to be

```
Pos1 | Pos2 
116  | 174
127  | 127
```

Comment: I don't understand your reproducible example, but `tail(yourdata, 2)` should select the last two rows (parts) of any vector, matrix, data.frame, function etc.

Comment: @Therkel I've added visual example

Comment: @Therkel I think they want the first two values reading right to left of every row, ignoring `NA`s

Comment: What if there is only one number in a row?

Comment: @Chris good question, I don't mind if it's ignored or not

Comment: @Gregor it comes from the 8th row `957594 115 116 120 613 127 127` last 2 values are `127` & `127`

Comment: @Gregor I agree that the use of the term "row" is misleading in the table of the desired output. The 127s are the last two entries in row 957594.

Comment: @Gregor I used a Reproduce Library to provide a reproducible example. you can ignore that. just look at the visual example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting to a matrix may speed things up:

```
ma = apply(as.matrix(tss2), MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) tail(na.omit(x), 2))

# risky version: should work *if* there aren't rows with exactly one non-missing element
matrix(unlist((ma)), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  116  174
# [2,]  127  127

# safe version
matrix(unlist((ma[sapply(ma, function(x) length(x) == 2)])), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
```

Comment: Hi @Gregor I got this error `Error in matrix(unlist((ma[sapply(ma, any)])), ncol = 2, byrow = T) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)`

Comment: for the second part isn't enough `matrix(unlist(ma), ncol = 2, byrow = T)` to do the trick?

Comment: It works like a charm on your sample data. If you can identify a subset of data that demonstrates the problem and share it I can try to debug, but I don't have a lot to go on as-is.

Comment: Hmmm, but could be risky if some rows only have one non-missing element. Updating to be safer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following loop:

```
new_data <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(tss2)) {
  new_data[[i]] <- tail(as.numeric(tss2[i, ][complete.cases(as.numeric(tss2[i, ]))]), 2)
}
new_data <- new_data[lapply(new_data, length) == 2]
new_data <- t(matrix(unlist(new_data), ncol = 2))
```

Comment: I added one more row to the code. Gregors code should be faster though.